# Windows Phone Reserve App name

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store

I need to release the app on the Windows Phone Store. When i add the App name and click on Reserve app name . Its shows as 'You can reserve another name for this app to use in another language or to change its name'. So can i still use the same name for the Application . However i need to use the same name for the Application. The Reserve app name changes to Associate App in my case. Is it possible to have multiple apps with same name in the Windows Phone Store.Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be a bit unclear. Which name are you referring to when you say `So can i still use the same name for the Application`

I'll make some points clear about name reservations in Windows Phone Store.

1. Windows Store can not have multiple apps with the same name now. It was possible previously till Windows Phone 8 but it is not possible now.
2. You reserve a name for your application that should match with the application name you will use in the application manifest.
3. You can reserve multiple names for an application. For example: You can reserve a name "Hello" for English version of the application and "Hola" for the spanish version of the application.
4. Multiple names can also be used when you could want to change name in the future. For example: you start developing an application now and is confused between two choices. So you can reserve both the names and will be able to publish your application with any of those names. The name that will be visible in the store will be the one present in your Application Manifest.